# highcharts Set Position of dataLabels not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to show a long pie chart (vertical) not the default (Horizontal)

so I set dataLabels of every data , to move the position to label

but seem like a bug or something , it didn't work

or maybe have another way to do this?

I am very need to solve this issue

very thankful

here is my code:

[http://jsfiddle.net/arhspt8011/Jgrdz/1](http://jsfiddle.net/arhspt8011/Jgrdz/1/)

```
        data: [
            {
                name:'Label1',
                y:50,
                dataLabels:
                    {
                        ebabled:false,
                        y:-200
                    }
            },
            {
                name:'Label2',
                y:50,
                dataLabels:
                    {
                        ebabled:true,
                        y:-200
                    }
            },
            {
                name:'Label3',
                y:50,
                dataLabels:
                    {
                        ebabled:true,
                        y:200
                    }
            }
        ]
```

the y of dataLabels didn't work OTZ

Comment: Could you update your jsfiddle, because it looks like wrong URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase width of chart, add spacingLeft / spacingRight, reduce chart size by "size" paramter. In case when you would like to have vertical datalabels, your can try to useHTML / formatter.